# mysql DATE_FORMAT STR_TO_DATE date subquery

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-format, str-to-date

Here is the `RECORDS` MySQL TABLE:

```
ID - BIGINT(20)
DATE - DATE
```

Records:

```
ID Date
1  2014-03-01
2  2014-03-02
3  2014-04-01
4  2014-04-02
```

Here is the first Query:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS date FROM records
WHERE
date >= STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y') AND
date <= STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y')
```

Everything is OKAY, I get the result:

```
3,2014-04-01
4,2014-04-02
```

But, when I try to get the date range with a subquery like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS date 
      FROM records) AS TEST
WHERE
date >= STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y') AND
date <= STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y')
```

I get an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Where is my mistake?

Comment: because of your subquery and the alias name is date in the outer query a string and not a date anymore.

Comment: Instead "date" in the subquery try "TEST.date "

Comment: I tried with:SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS date FROM records) AS TEST
WHERE
TEST.date >= STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y') AND
TEST.date <= STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y')

I get again empty result set!

Comment: @user3623185 In your case I would avoid the subquery.

Comment: @user3623185 Try SELECT date instead of SELECT *

Comment: Why not just provide the date in the correct format to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, you wish to just return the date in `%d/%m/%Y` format.
The results I'm getting for your first query in your question do actually yield this converted date, are you sure that's the query you used?

Either way, if this is what you want, I believe you should change the query to something like this:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS datestring FROM records
WHERE
date >= STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y') AND
date <= STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y')
```

Even though the date column is used in the comparison rather than the alias, i think it clarifies things.

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/594b7/8) showing the results, as you can see your first query is returning the desired result.

Comment: That's  the way I would go too: simple without the  unnecessary subquery (+1).

Answer (score 0):

you have to include your where clause in TEST.

```
  SELECT * 
 FROM (SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS date 
  FROM records
 WHERE
 date >= STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y') AND
 date <= STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y') 
   ) AS TEST
```

But i dont know what the reason to use subquery here ?

EDIT:

try this

```
 select * FROM(
 SELECT id, CASE WHEN date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y')
                           AND STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y') 
                 THEN DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') 
            END AS date 
 FROM records
) as TEST
WHERE //////  some other conditions
```

Comment: I don't want it to be in the subquery, is there any other solution?

Comment: I really need something like this:
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS date 
      FROM records) AS TEST
WHERE
SOMETHING HERE

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, date FROM records) AS TEST
WHERE
date >= STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y') AND
date <= STR_TO_DATE('30/04/2014','%d/%m/%Y') 

Everything is working like this, but I want to convert displayed date as %d%m%Y before display it without using PHP or any other language

Answer (score 0):

DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP are naturally ordered data types. That is, they do what you expect when you use inequalities and the BETWEEN statement.

Their default text representation -- 2014-05-07 11:59:56 -- also happens to be naturally ordered when sorted as text.

But when you do DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') you convert the naturally ordered representation to one that is not naturally ordered.

```
    03/15/2014  will sort before
    03/16/2013
```

even though it is not, in fact, before.

If you want to do date arithmetic, you need to keep the dates in a naturally ordered form until they're actually displayed. Most people don't use DATE_FORMAT() in SQL to convert dates to to a displayable format; instead they use a Java or PHP program to do the display. That way the dates remain naturally ordered.

In your question your outer query can't tell that it's doing BETWEEN on dates. You've told it to do BETWEEN on strings, that don't happen to be naturally ordered.

You said in your comment to @echo_Me's question you don't want BETWEEN in the subquery. You either must put the DATE_FORMAT in the outer query or BETWEEN in the subquery.